# DNS redirect in Win8 like it was possible with hosts file

Tags: windows-8, redirection, hosts

there was a time when you could redirect a server for debugging purpose simply by changing the windows hosts file.

This does not work with windows 8.

So what is the easiest way to redirect (let's say) superuser.com to localhost on windows 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8 can and does use the host file, but there are some complications, formost being windows Defender detects it as a trace of malware.

see the instructions here for whitelisting the file in windows defender
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2764944

and info on editing a hosts file
http://www.jafaloo.com/2013/01/03/windows-hosts-file/

Comment: [How to edit hosts file in Windows 8? Defender says malware detected](http://superuser.com/questions/502209/how-to-edit-hosts-file-in-windows-8-defender-says-malware-detected)