# Windows 10 hosts file entries get blocked automatically by # sign after some times

Tags: hosts-file

My OS is Windows 10. I have entered a few entries in my hosts file. But after some time or after reboot there is a # sign in the beginning of each entry. I did it using Administrator Account also. Note that I am using Bitdefender Internet Security 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made the hosts file read-only after update. Now it is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Very likely, your antivirus suite is changing your hosts file. An old school attack vector for malware is to redirect DNS lookups by modifying the hosts file, so keeping it intact makes good sense.

But - if you actually need to change it like you do, you need to figure out how to stop your antivirus software from reverting your changes. I personally use Webroot which does something similar.

Google pointed me to [this search result](http://forum.bitdefender.com/index.php?showtopic=59600) which suggests that you may be able to solve your problem by adding the hosts file to an exceptions list in your antivirus suite.

Also, your machine might very well be running Windows Defender alongside your antivirus solution. Windows Defender may also revert changes to the hosts file. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/502209/how-to-edit-hosts-file-in-windows-8-defender-says-malware-detected) question for more on that.